# Launchers for installed snap applications (including Ubuntu Software) disappeared after installing GNOME Software

Tags: software-center, gnome-shell, snap, flatpak, gnome-software

I installed regular `gnome-software` to be able to install Flatpaks as well. Right after I did that, all was fine: I could see both "Software" and "Ubuntu software" in the launcher overview and launch either of them.

However, after a restart, I could no longer see Ubuntu Software, and installed Snaps weren't present in the menu anymore either. I have since uninstalled gnome-software, un- and re-installed both Ubuntu Software (`snap remove snap-store` and `snap install snap-store`) and the Snap app I'm testing with, and restarted, but I still can't see them.

Why did that happen?

As requested by pomsky:

```
$ ls /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/
chromium_chromium.desktop
gnome-system-monitor_gnome-system-monitor.desktop
keepassxc_keepassxc.desktop
mimeinfo.cache
signal-desktop_signal-desktop.desktop
skype_skypeforlinux.desktop
snap-store_snap-store.desktop
spotify_spotify.desktop
ubports-installer_ubports-installer.desktop
```

and

```
$ echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS
/home/vincent/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.desktop` launchers associated to the Snap Store and other snap applications are present in your `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` directory. Under a normal circumstance GNOME Shell should be able to detect them and show them in the application list. But the output of `echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS` shows that this directory is not a part of your `XDG_DATA_DIRS`. So add the `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/` directory to your `XDG_DATA_DIRS`.

Also as a workaround, you may copy the required `.desktop` launchers from `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` to your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory. For example, for the Snap Store app, you can do that by running

```
cp /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/snap-store_snap-store.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

Comment: Thanks! I added `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/` to my `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`, and now I can see my applications again. The only change since before is that "Ubuntu Software" is now called "Snap Store", so I'm not sure if I can still use it to install Debian Packages.