# If I remove snap-store, what impact will this have on already installed snaps?

Tags: uninstall, snap

Will I still be able to use installed snap apps without any limitations, except perhaps the update feature?
Xubuntu 20.04lts

Comment: You haven't provided any release details, and your question seems vague to me, however recent Lubuntu & Kubuntu releases don't include the GNOME/Ubuntu Software store (snap store) without any ill-effects. They both include by default Discover as their program store, and `muon` as the package manager; no effects there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will be able to continue using your existing snaps.

They will refresh (update) normally.

You can use the command-line to install more snaps, remove existing ones, and, generally, do most everything, if not more, than if you used the snap store.

`man snap` is worth reading carefully.

You can also visit the snap store "online": https://snapcraft.io/store

For managing your regular software, use the command-line or install Synaptic Package Manager (`sudo apt update`, `sudo apt full-upgrade` and `sudo apt install synaptic`) and use that.

---

**Edit:**

One convenience the snap store installed on your system offers is that of modifying the permissions you wish a snap to use (*from the set of permissions the developer has made available*).

Take the example of the `okular` snap. On the snap store's page for `okular`, there's a Permissions button (assuming that the `okular` snap is installed). Clicking on it produces the GUI in the image below:

[image: Permissions GUI]

You can easily change any of the permissions available but you'll obviously need to provide your password when prompted.

You can view the existing permissions via the terminal using `snap connections okular`. For convenience, I modified the command and trimmed the output width a bit:

```
$ snap connections | grep -E "(Interface|okular)" | nl
1     Interface                                     Plug                          Slot                 Notes
2     content[kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18-all]  okular:kde-frameworks-5-plug  kde-frameworks-5 ... -
3     desktop                                       okular:desktop                :desktop             -
4     desktop-legacy                                okular:desktop-legacy         :desktop-legacy      -
5     home                                          okular:home                   :home                -
6     unity7                                        okular:unity7                 :unity7              -
7     x11                                           okular:x11                    :x11                 -
$
```

Then, I changed a permission to allow the snap to access removable media via the GUI as shown below:

[image: Modified permissions]

For comparison, I ran the same terminal command again:

```
$ snap connections | grep -E "(Interface|okular)" | nl                                             
1     Interface                                     Plug                          Slot                 Notes
2     content[kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18-all]  okular:kde-frameworks-5-plug  kde-frameworks-5 ... -
3     desktop                                       okular:desktop                :desktop             -
4     desktop-legacy                                okular:desktop-legacy         :desktop-legacy      -
5     home                                          okular:home                   :home                -
6     removable-media                               okular:removable-media        :removable-media     manual
7     unity7                                        okular:unity7                 :unity7              -
8     x11                                           okular:x11                    :x11                 -
$
```

There is now an additional line relating to *removable media* with "manual" in the Notes column.

If we want to, for example, *undo* the permission we just granted, `man snap` tells us we need to use `disconnect` and the formula suggested is `snap disconnect <snap>:<plug> <snap>:<slot>` (with `sudo`) but what worked for me is

```
sudo snap disconnect okular:removable-media
```

The change was immediately seen by running `snap connections | grep -E "(Interface|okular)" | nl` with a return to just seven lines of output.

The snap store reflected the change after logging out and back in!

Comment: Ooo, I didn't notice the "Permissions" button... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I uninstalled snap store from my Ubuntu 20.04 and I can still use the apps that already had, but they must be launched from Terminal because they don't appear on the installed apps list and the icon on my desktop also disappeared.

You can then solve the new issue by consulting [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1237377/480481).

Comment: So this solves the problem and then creates another one, right?

Comment: @ThunderBird This can be solved: https://askubuntu.com/q/1237377/480481

Comment: @pomsky I have thus edited the answer to contain that link... It wasn't obvious. Thanks :)